# _layouts/CreatePage.aspx throwing error

Tags: publishing-page

_layouts/CreatePage.aspx is throwing following error for a given site collection.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Request timed out. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  
Stack Trace: 
[HttpException (0x80004005): Request timed out.]
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5456; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5456
```

Howerver, I can create publishing pages on a different site collection.

publishing feature is enabled on both site. The uls logs (just entering createpage.aspx then httpexception then existing monitoring) does not show anything specific. Any help.

===== Updated =====

I tried this another site collection that uses "BDR = Document Center" template. I am getting this error in the uls. But this link (http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2011/09/15/common-error-the-site-is-not-valid-the-pages-document-library-is-missing-error.aspx) resolves the following issue.

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.InvalidPublishingWebException: The site is not valid. The 'Pages' document library is missing.   
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb.GetPublishingListWithCleanup(PublishingListType list, Boolean throwExceptionOnInvalidWeb)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.BasePageSettingsPage.get_PageListRoot()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.BasePageSettingsPage.SetParentUrlLabel()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.BasePageSettingsPage.LoadValues()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.CreatePagePage.LoadValues()    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.BasePageSettingsPage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CodeBehind.CreatePagePage.OnLoad(EventArgs e)    
 at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()    
 at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Comment: See WFE-servers windows event log.

Comment: I dont see anything specific in WFE windows log.

Comment: I am still strugling with this. I deactivated and activated Publishing Feature at the site collection and site level. ULS log does not show whole lot. Can anyone please suggest?

Comment: An old post, but can you tell me if you ever found out what the issue was?